# Nginx: Cache uWSGI as accessible files

Tags: nginx, debian, cache, wsgi

I'm still pretty new to Nginx, but I know that it serves static files very well. For this reason I want to use Nginx together with TileStache as a map server.

TileStache has got a [WSGI application](http://tilestache.org/doc/#wsgi) that should work well with Nginx's [uWSGI module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule) (haven't tested yet). The map tiles should be cached as static PNG files that could be delivered directly to the user, I'm not sure how though.

How far have I come to achieve this, or have I taken the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong. Nginx supports the protocol, but doesn't seem to have its own application. Now I'm using [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) as a middleman, and it works very well.